# Wordpress Back-end can't be accessed anymore (suddenly, no changed made)

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a website that runs perfectly. Yesterday suddenly our links to content started returning 404s. Admin page is unreachable. When I try to go to the admin page it shows a white page with only 'Wordpress installatie: OK' (Installatie is just dutch for install).

I have tried backing up the plugin folder and then removing the plugin folder entirely but the error remains.

Anyone has any idea? Please let me know if you need any other information. I was unsure of what else to add.

Comment: Settings->Permalink->update Try it.!

Comment: @hemnathmouli I can't access the admin page

Comment: Can you show the website.?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing wp-admin folder with the latest download,or simply go through list of all files using filezilla and check if any of your core file is corrupted (i.e file memory will show 0bytes).
also try enabling the debug from wp-config.php to check if site is having any fatal error, set WP_DEBUG to true.
IF setting WP_DEBUG doesn't shows any error then try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

to your site, this will display you the errors.

Comment: This returns 1 error that says I should change a line of code to use '__construct()' in versions 4.3 or higher.